# How to add/remove menu items at runtime in ICS?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm using the ActionBarCompat sample that comes with the SDK. My activity used to have menu items that would change based on the state of the activity. I would modify the menu like so in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();

    if (some condition) {
        menu.add(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

In ICS however, I believe we're supposed to modify menu items by calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and then our `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called again. Here we can remove menu items (not add them). So then we might end up with something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (SDK >= 11) {
        // full menu is reloaded from xml every time we 
        // called invalidateOptionsMenu(), so we have a
        // fresh menu here again.
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (SDK >= 11) {
        // we can remove items depending on our state, 
        // but not add any, that's ok.
    }
    else {
        // we only have our original menu instance here,
        // so if we previously had called menu.remove(),
        // we need to call menu.add() here:
        if (foo == true) {
            menu.remove(R.id.menu_item_foo);
        } else {
            menu.add(R.id.menu_item_foo, ...);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems a bit awkward,

Thanks

Comment: just making sure, you do call `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(..)` at the end, right?

Comment: Hi yes. After looking at this some more, it seems like in SDK 11+ we can call invalidateOptionsMenu(), but we don't have the same in earlier versions. So wondering how we rebuild the menu on earlier platforms while keeping the code consistent.

Comment: Use menu.clear and rebuild the menu you want at the time you want it. InvalidateOptionsMenu is there because there is no physical menu key to press (when using the Actionbar model) so it needs to be told when to update.

Answer (score 1):

Demo project
https://github.com/AlienAsRoger/CourtDeadlines

This is how i solved it:

In ActionBarHelperBase.java of actionbarcompat project

...

```
private View addActionItemCompatFromMenuItem(final MenuItem item) {

final int itemId = item.getItemId();
```

....

The creator of this class copy properties of object, but didn't copy the id of item, so it is impossible to find it later with fiven id.

So i added it in that method:

```
...
actionButton.setId(itemId);
...
```

and in the same class i just use:

```
@Override
public void hideMenuItemById(int id, boolean show){
    getActionBarCompat().findViewById(id).setVisibility(show? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
}
```

Hope it helps You.

**UPDATES:**

in ActionBarActivity from ActionBarCompat sample:

```
package com.chess.ui.activities;

import actionbarcompat.ActionBarActivity;
import actionbarcompat.ActionBarHelper;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import com.chess.R;
import com.chess.lcc.android.LccHolder;

public abstract class CoreActivityActionBar2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected boolean showActionSearch;
    protected boolean showActionSettings;
    protected boolean showActionNewGame;
    protected boolean showActionRefresh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && getActionBar() != null) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (HONEYCOMB_PLUS_API) {
            adjustActionBar();
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!HONEYCOMB_PLUS_API) {
            adjustActionBar();
        }
    }


    private void adjustActionBar() {
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_settings, showActionSettings);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_new_game, showActionNewGame);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_refresh, showActionRefresh);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_search, showActionSearch);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_singOut, LccHolder.getInstance(this).isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.sign_out, menu);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_singOut, LccHolder.getInstance(this).isConnected(), menu);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_search, showActionSearch, menu);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_settings, showActionSettings, menu);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_new_game, showActionNewGame, menu);
        getActionBarHelper().showMenuItemById(R.id.menu_refresh, showActionRefresh, menu);

        if (HONEYCOMB_PLUS_API) {
            // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                backToHomeActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesScreenActivity.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public ActionBarHelper provideActionBarHelper() {
        return getActionBarHelper();
    }

}
```

where `showActionSettings` is a boolean flag to switch visibility

Comment: How do I call this method from my activity?

Comment: I dont get how this is supposed to work. Why do you only add the showMenuById method in the HelperBase (this is only pre Honeycomp)? Your code does not work because you do not call the method in HelperBase but in ActionBarHelper.

Comment: Please see demo project for implementation 
https://github.com/AlienAsRoger/CourtDeadlines

Comment: In what file should I look. Your actionbarcompat files seem to be untouched. There are not the changes you are mentioning in your post.

Comment: I just wanted to try this solution. Does this have the latest update?

Comment: ActionBarHelper does not have this showMenuItemById method. Could you explain your solution please? I think you've nailed the problem but I can't understand the solution exactly.

Comment: How do you get a handle on the action items in your own code? One way to get it is in onOptionsItemSelected which gives you the item but if I need to manipulate the action items depending on when different fragments are shown, how do I get the handle on them? This is a blocking problem.